# How to read QR code in windows phone 8.1 app development?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code

I want to scan QR code in windows phone app 8.1.I am tried lot of examples but no one is work for me.
Below code I tried but no use

```
 xmlns:jwqr="clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"
```

in xaml

```
<jwqr:QRCodeScanner
    ScanComplete="QRCodeScanner_ScanComplete"
    Error="QRCodeScanner_Error"
    Width="400"
    Height="400"/>
```

It showing error like:

> The name "QRCodeScanner" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"

And tried the [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Capture-QR-code-in-Windows-f665a28d) this one also not working for me. But in this camera not scan the code. 
Please anyone help me. If you have any other links. I am trying this last 3 days but till now I am not getting any answer correctly. 
Plase help me.......

Comment: @Mega Tron please give me any links if u have..

Comment: the library you're using, may causing the issue. try using another library to scan QR code. There are simple ways out there to scan QR code.

Comment: @Keval Langalia please provide any links.

Comment: Jeff Wilcox control is for Sliverlight based win 8.1 apps and I think you are making a native (non-silverlight) app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending but i've used [Zxing Library](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) for Barcode/QR code scanning and that worked for me.

here's a sample how to use this library:

```
// create a barcode reader instance
IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
// load a bitmap
var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.LoadFrom("C:\\sample-barcode-image.png");
// detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
// do something with the result
if (result != null)
{
   txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
   txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;
}
```

Documentation and other demoClient is available [here](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/117068)

Ask if you require more code. Hope that helps..!

Comment: Thanks .I will check and tell you

Comment: I didn't find any code in that link please provide sample code.

Comment: please anyone help me.

Comment: In the above code Bitmap showing error."The namespace couldnot be found".

Comment: in that  ZXing Library link  I didn't find any sorce code.please help me

Comment: check this thread. it might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23d320e6-36f3-462f-ad75-7ff076620394/need-to-scan-qr-codes-in-wp81-using-zxing?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: ok. I found  sample code. but in that code camera scaning is not working.Its only put  image in  file path.I want to camera open and scan the qrcode.